# Python remove word from bigram in list without returning a new list

Tags: python-3.x

Just quick side question. Is there a way and if, how to remove/delete a specific word from a bigram in a list (**must be the same list!**) that also contains just words. E.g.

In:

```py
x = ['Peter Parker', 'Hugo', 'Fischerman']
```

Task, delete Parker from that same list:
Expected output:

```py
x as ['Peter', 'Hugo', 'Fischerman']
```

I tried to use `xx = [x.replace('Parker, '') for x in xx]`but it seems to give me a new list in the sack.

Any ideas?

Comment: List comprehension always creates a new list, so you'd have to iterate over the list and modify the contents at an index. Something along the lines of `for i in enumerate(x): x[i]=x.replace('Parker', '')`

Comment: By the way someone likely downvoted this because modifying an element in a python list in-place has been covered pretty extensively on StackOverflow, so this is a repeat question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = ['Peter Parker', 'Hugo', 'Fischerman'] # initialize list
for item in range(len(list)): # loop
    list[item] = list[item].replace("Parker", "").strip() # replace item nu=umber "item" with its fixed result, replacing "Parker" with nothing and stripping - this just does nothing if "Parker" is not in item number "item".
```

That should work, just omit the list initialization to add it wherever (and don't forget to fix the variable names!)